# Not interpolate missing dates in Highcharts

Tags: date, highcharts

I have a datetime series in Highcharts. The incoming data has some missing dates. Highcharts, by default, interpolates for those missing dates. I want it to interpret as if the data for those dates is 0. One way, obviously, is to add null data for these dates in my input data to Highcharts. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [ordinal](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal) parameter as false.

Answer (score 1):

You could set [`connectNulls`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.connectNulls) to false. This will cause a break to appear in the line (if you are using a line).